# Концепция именования в MVVM

Tags: ооп, mvvm, архитектура

Мне очень нравится идея System Metaphor и я хочу применить ее к своему проекту. Но я не очень понимаю, как увязать ее с паттернами. Например, с MVVM (который тоже применяю в своем проекте). Сейчас у меня имеются следующие модули:

```
View
ViewModel
Model
Utils
```

Я уже придумал метафору для логику моего приложения (модуль `Model`). Но что делать с `View` и `ViewModel`? В реальной жизни нет никакой модели представления, никакой проблемы отделения отрисовки от логики отрисовки. Можно конечно с натяжкой подобрать метафору типа настройки фотоаппарата (`ViewModel`) и самими снимком (`View`). Но она совершенно не вяжется с метафорой, которую я придумал для `Model`

В связи с этим вопросы:

1. Применяется ли практика использования в одном приложении нескольких метафор, не связанных друг с другом?
2. Может быть применяется практика задания метафоры только для части приложения?
3. Может быть в данном случае приоритетным считается концепция именования, диктуемая паттерном и нужно отказаться вообще от всяческих метафор?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, VM — это всё же не «логика отрисовки», а «объекты с точки зрения приложения» (в отличие от «точки зрения модели»).

Comment: @VladD, пусть так, но все равно все 3 вопроса остаются)